# pick between several actions using percentage

Tags: c#, math, logic

I have an Object with X amount of hobbies, each hobby has a value between 0-100 (representing %), and together they add up to 100.

Every morning I want to run a  function that decides what that Object is going to do, and the higher value a hobby has, the more likely they are to be chosen.

I cannot figure out how to translate that last part into code. Using these variables for example:

```
    int fishing = 25;
    int sleeping = 25;
    int drinking = 50;
    int running = 0;
```

Comment: Yes, but say I randomize number 23. Then what? The only way I see around this is for every hobby to have a range. i.e 0-24, 25-50, 51-100

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work for you:

```
 class Program
{
    private static List<KeyValuePair<string, int>> Actions = new List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>()
    {
        new KeyValuePair<string, int>("fishing", 25),
        new KeyValuePair<string, int>("sleeping", 25),
        new KeyValuePair<string, int>("drinking", 5),
        new KeyValuePair<string, int>("running", 0),
    };

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var result = Actions.OrderByDescending(r => r.Value).First();

        Console.WriteLine(result.Key);
    }
}
```

This assumes that you already have the actions and their percentage. Now if any 2 (or more) of the items have the same percentage, it will show the first one added to the list.

**EDIT**

Sorry didn't get the requirement for randomization. Try this:

```
var listOfActionsToTake = new List<string>() { "fishing", "sleeping", "drinking", "running" };

        var listOFActions = new List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>();

        var rand = new Random();
        var currentPercentage = 101;


        for (int i = 0; i < listOfActionsToTake.Count; i++)
        {
            var current = rand.Next(currentPercentage);
            if (i == listOfActionsToTake.Count - 1)
            {
                current = currentPercentage - 1;
            }
            listOFActions.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>(listOfActionsToTake[i], current));

            currentPercentage -= current;
        }
        foreach (var action in listOFActions)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{action.Key}: {action.Value}");
        }

        var result = listOFActions.OrderByDescending(r => r.Value).First();

        Console.WriteLine(result.Key);
```

Like this, no matter how many values you add to the `listOfActionsToTake` you will always end up with a sum of 100 between them, and the biggest will be selected

Comment: where does the randomization take place?

Comment: @Majs - sorry, didn't get this requirement. Check the updated answer

Answer (score 0):

I found [this](http://www.vcskicks.com/random-element.php) example and it seems to make sense. You add the values to get a cumulative value. If the random value created is less then the cumulative probability, then the current item is the selected.

Basically, if that condition is false, then you *ignore* the current items probability from the condition. So the next item to be compared now has a higher probability to be chosen.

For example:

```
// 1. RandNum = 0.4
// 2. cumulative = 0.0
// 3. fishing = 0.25
// 4. cumulative = cumulative + fishing = 0.25
// 5. RandNum < cumulative ? false
```

The random number was `0.4` and fishing has a probably of `0.25` to be selected. Since fishing's probability is lower then the random number, we add it to the cumulative value and essentially ignore it in the next item. The next item will now have a higher probability to be chosen because now it's just `sleeping` and `drinking`. They now both have a `.50` probability to be chosen.

```
// 1. RandNum = 0.4
// 2. cumulative = 0.25
// 3. sleeping = 0.25
// 4. cumulative = cumulative + sleeping = .50
// 5. RanNum < cumulative ? true
```

Although you would have to modify it to account for when the percentages are equal since it'll just take the first one. You could check if the percentages are the same after finding an inital action to do. If the randomly chosen action has the same percentage as another, then randomly pick one of them.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int fishing = 25;
    int sleeping = 25;
    int drinking = 50;
    int running = 0;

    List<KeyValuePair<string, double>> elements = new List<KeyValuePair<string, double>>();
    elements.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, double>("fishing", (fishing * (1.0 / 100.0)))); // 25 * (1 /100) = .25
    elements.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, double>("sleeping", (sleeping * (1.0 / 100.0))));
    elements.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, double>("drinking", (drinking * (1.0 / 100.0))));
    elements.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, double>("running", (running * (1.0 / 100.0))));


    Random r = new Random();
    double rand = r.NextDouble();

    double cumulative = 0.0;
    string selectedElement = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < elements.Count; i++)
    {
        cumulative += elements[i].Value;
        if (rand < cumulative)
        {
            selectedElement = elements[i].Key;
            break;
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Selected Element: " + selectedElement);
    Console.ReadKey();
}

// Test 1: rand: 0.522105917
//         cumulative: 1
//         Selected Element: drinking
// Test 2: rand: 0.49201479
//         cumulative: 0.5
//         Selected Element: sleeping
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it and will work when they don't add to 100 too.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

class Program
{
    static Dictionary<string, int> activities = new Dictionary<string, int>
    {
        { "running", 0 },
        { "fishing", 25 },
        { "sleeping", 25 },
        { "drinking", 50 }
    };

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int sum = activities.Sum(a => a.Value);
        int rand = new Random().Next(sum);
        int total = -1;
        string activity = activities.SkipWhile(a => (total += a.Value) < rand).First().Key;
        Console.WriteLine(activity);
    }
}
```